# How to use eval() for php code stored in DB?

Tags: php

I have whole HTML code present in the db and it includes following HTML code-

```
<p class="card mb-4 shadow-sm"><img src="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>/assets/images/blog/php.png" alt="php" title="php"></p>
```

This HTML is stored in db and I want it to print value of SITE_URL when it gets fetched because SITE_URL is dynamic (const here in this case).

I tried using PHP's own eval() function like the one mentioned in this [article](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php/example-4662#example-4662). But it's not working.

what would be the better way to do this OR
is there any other way to figure out this ?

Here, what I tried.

```
<p class="card mb-4 shadow-sm"><img src="<?php 
$str = SITE_URL;
eval('\$str = \'$str\';');
echo $str; ?>/assets/images/blog/php.png" alt="php" title="php"></p>
```

Comment: _"But it's not working"_ means what _exactly?

Comment: No reason that eval shouldn't work. However, unless you need complex expressions, a simpler placheolder/templating syntax `%SITE_URL%` and preg_replace_callback might be more appropriate.

Comment: Let me check given link above.

Comment: If I use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2120121/7362396) it correctly "evals" your HTML/PHP. However, you also asked for a better way: If it's only about the SITE_URL, maybe save `%%SITE_URL%%` in DB and `str_replace` that?

Comment: I think the better is to store inside string variables, ex. %SITE_URL% and use `str_replce('%SITE_URL%', SITE_URL, $string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you know how dodgy using eval is..

As long as `SITE_URL` is defined, it would be fine. Then you would do something like:

```
<?php
define('SITE_URL', 'http://example.com');

$str = '<p class="card mb-4 shadow-sm"><img src="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>/assets/images/blog/php.png" alt="php" title="php"></p>';

echo eval('?>'.$str);
```

https://3v4l.org/EEB54

---

An alternative to using eval, is to use a template and replace the placeholders with the values you define.

```
<?php
define('SITE_URL', 'http://example.com');

$vars = [
    'SITE_URL' => SITE_URL    
];

$template = '<p class="card mb-4 shadow-sm"><img src="{{ SITE_URL }}/assets/images/blog/php.png" alt="php" title="php"></p>';

// match any single word with _ or -, with spaces either side or not
// e.g: {{key}} or {{ key }} or {{key-foo}} or {{ key-foo }}
//  not {{ a b c }}
$str = preg_replace_callback("/{{[ ]{0,}([\w\_-]{1,})[ ]{0,}}}/", function ($match) use ($vars) {
    return array_key_exists($match[1], $vars) ? $vars[$match[1]] : '';
}, $template);


echo $str;
```

https://3v4l.org/cUK5B

Or look into using a template engine if you need more features.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks :)