# How to get PHP variable from another file?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer, server-side

I'm trying to make a forgot password system with PHPMailer on xampp.
But when I send an email,the email body is a html mail template,what I get from another file `$mail->Body = file_get_contents('mail_template.php');`,and I have problem,because I don't know how should I get the data of the `$url` variable and send it to `mail_template.php` file to use it for the link in the mail.
I tried the `include 'filename.php';` command,but haven't worked.

Here is the code:

```
if (isset($_POST["submitButton"])) {
    $emailTo = $_POST["email"];

    $code = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    $query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO resetpasswords(code,email) VALUES('$code', '$emailTo')");
    $query->execute();
    if (!$query) {
        exit("Something went wrong...");
    }

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    try {
        //Server settings                                           // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'mail@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'password';                               // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
        $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('mail@mail.com', 'Email');
        $mail->addAddress($emailTo);     // Add a recipient
        $mail->addReplyTo('no-reply@website.com', 'No reply');


        // Content
        $url = "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "/resetPassword/code/$code";
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Reset your password!';
        $mail->Body = file_get_contents('mail_template.php');
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

        $mail->send();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
    header("refresh:10;url=login.php");
}
```

So from this php file,I want to send the data of the `$url` to the `mail_template.php`

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Please show us the contents of `mail_template.php` so we can see where/how it is expecting to receive the URL.

Comment: The `mail_template.php` is 121 row length. So I think there is no reason to show the full data.
Here is a short code from the file:
`<a data-click-track-id="37" href="<?php echo $url; ?>" style=".........">Reset Password </a>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Eval that evaluates HTML & PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309800/php-eval-that-evaluates-html-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send data to another url in php you have to try the following url:

```
`mail_template.php?data=mail@gmail.com`
```

then inside an empty mail_template.php do -

```
 <?php 
    if (isset($_GET['data'])) {
      $test = $_GET['data'];
//print the data added to the url
      echo $test;
    }
    ?>
```